# Format of data in a column in a data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have read a fixed width file and created a dataframe.
I have a field called claim number which is of length 15.In the data frame I see this field appearing as "1.902431e+14" rather than full 15 length claim number.

how can I resolve this so that I can see entire 15 length of claim number in data frame ?

Answer (score 0):

For example, use pandas float_format option as follows:

```
#data claim_number dictionary
dictionary = {'claim_number': [1.902431111111141]}

#specification of claim number format
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.15f}'.format

#Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dictionary)
```

If you want to apply your format specifically to one column only, you can use style.format instead of pd.options.float_format as follows:

```
#data claim_number dictionary
dictionary = {'claim_number_1': [1.902431111111141], 'claim_number_2': ['some_string'], 'claim_number_3': [0.2323]}

#Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dictionary)

#style format single column 
df.style.format({'claim_number_1': "{:,.15f}"})
```

More options on how to use style.format can be found here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way I can apply to single column of a data frame only ?